# MySql Adding value on update

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this update:

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET prioridade = @prioridade, situacao = @sit , responsavel = @resp , previsao_termino = @previsao, chamado_designado = @designado WHERE id = @id";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@prioridade", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ch.Prioridade_ID;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@sit", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ch.Situacao_ID;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@resp", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ch.Responsavel_ID;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@previsao", MySqlDbType.Date)).Value = ch.Previsao_Termino;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@designado", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ch.Chamado_Designado;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = ch.ID;
_dal.Executar(cmd);
```

the value of `ch.Previsao_Termino` is equal to `31/05/2013` the field `previsao_termino` is a `date type`. When it will make the `update` it throws me an error saying that:

```
Wrong Value for the field previsao_termino 0031-05-2013.
```

Where did that `00` came from ? Maybe the connector ? I updated my connector to a new version, also i updated my `VisualStudio 2010` to `VisualStudio 2012` and sinced I changed that, i've got a lot of problems u.u.

Comment: What is the data type of `ch.Previsao_Termino`?

Comment: What type is `ch.Previsao_Termino`? DateTime or String?

Comment: @Marco  It's a `string`

Comment: And so here is the error !!! If you want to write a string to a date in db you should use yyyy-MM-dd format. Naturally, if you use a DateTime this is the best you can do!!!

Comment: @NikitaSilverstruk But it always worked this way... But since I changed my `connector` and my `vs` problems started to appear everywhere u.u

Comment: Try setting the value as `DateTime.ParseExact(ch.Previsao_Termino, 'dd/MM/yyyy', null)`.

Comment: Where? Considering it always worked the way it is... @Marco Should I try change it to `DateTime`?

Comment: If you want to write a DateTime value using a DateTime parameter, you MUST use a DateTime to avoid strange (and unneeded) conversions!

Comment: I'll change it @Marco and see what happens

Comment: Excellent - boa sorte!

Comment: I need to leave now guys, just saying that the conversion you showed me @EdGibbs worked !

Comment: My boss is telling me to leave HAHA ! I'll try to change string to DateTime next @Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @EdGibbs

When working with `MySqlCommand.Parameters` the variable you are passing as its value, `MUST` be the same type that you set the parameter.  e.g

```
MySqlCommand.Parameter.Add(new MySqlParameter("@ParamName", MySqlDataType.DateTime)).value = dtValue
```

the varaible `dtvalue` MUST BE DATETIME TYPE, if like me you are using `string`, then you should use the following conversion.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(ch.Previsao_Termino, 'dd/MM/yyyy', null)
```